# Using Pandas series values as index for assigning values to another series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a shortcut to assigning a pandas series from elements in a list.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,2183],[1,4,2235],[2,3,6123],[3,4,4213]],columns=['month','staff','sales'])

goals=[1346,4456,4574]

df['goals']=goals[df['month']-1]
```

The last line throws an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series`

Desired output looks like this:

```
   month  staff  sales  goals
0      1      2   2183   1346
1      1      4   2235   1346
2      2      3   6123   4456
3      3      3   4213   4574
```

This is a general case, and in the future, the goals array might actually be multidimensional.

Comment: what about: `df['goals']=goals`?

Comment: I gave a simple example. In reality, there might be a number of months that need to be looked up and not in order in the Pandas series. Goals will always be in order.

Comment: Great question, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
In [80]: mapping = pd.Series(goals, index=df.month.unique())

In [81]: mapping
Out[81]:
1    1346
2    4456
3    4574
dtype: int64

In [82]: df['goals'] = df.month.map(mapping)

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   month  staff  sales  goals
0      1      2   2183   1346
1      1      4   2235   1346
2      2      3   6123   4456
3      3      4   4213   4574
```

Comment: Can this work for goals determined by month and staff#? A matrix of goals?

Comment: @hrschbck, i don't understand  - what is `matrix of goals`?

Comment: If the goal depended on both the month and the staff#, if Goal(month=1,staff=2)=1500 and Goal(month=1,staff=4)=1346?

Comment: @hrschbck, please ask a new question and provide there a corresponding data sets (input and output)...

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
```

First, a dictionary of values for goals and their respective months:

```
goals_dict = dict(zip(np.arange(1,len(goals)+1), goals))
```

Now use `map`

```
df['goals'] = df.month.map(goals_dict)
```